# Firebase android user authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase for my android application. I am using firebase authentication using email and password, but I need to save student id of user along with email and password on which I want to keep a check that it is unique. I tried adding extra info student ID by first saving email and pass then I got its uid and save national id in database using that same uid , but the problem is I want to check if that national id is unique or not.

```
 firebaseDatabase= database.getReference("USERS");

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {


                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            String userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            DatabaseReference dr = firebaseDatabase.child(userId);
                            dr.child("studentID").setValue(sID);
                            pr.dismiss();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, home.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Already Registered!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            pr.dismiss();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connection Problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            pr.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: `need to save national id of user along with email and password` be sure you have a working understanding of the security issues involved - ideally, passwords never hit network or permanent storage.

Comment: I have edited the situation can you tell me now how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Before save the extra info you must read the database and find por the national id, if firebase return a value, the id exists, otherwise you can create a node in the database named as your ID.